# Can someone explain mdict in python (scipy.io), for example in scipy.io.savemat()?

Tags: python, matlab, io, scipy

I have been working on loading some files in python, and then once the files are loaded I want to export them into a .mat file and do the rest of the processing in MATLAB. I understand that I can do this with:

```
    import scipy.io as sio
    # load some files, assign loaded data to variables
    # ...
    sio.savemat(filename,mdict)
```

I understand to a point what is going on here and have seen the syntax for this as something like:

```
    alist = [5,3,6]
    sio.savemat('small_list.mat',mdict={'alist':alist})
```

Can someone explain exactly what I am doing in the second part of the argument for `sio.savemat()` argument, i.e. `mdict = {'alist':alist}`? I may just be confused on something that is more pythonic (I am relatively new to python and coming from a background working mostly with C++), but I am confused by what the mdict term is doing in terms of which parts of the syntax are doing what (is the quoted part the name of my variable in MATLAB, and the unquoted my variable in python?)

Additionally, what would this look like if I wanted to save (and then load in MATLAB) a few distinct variables in one `.mat` file?

Comment: According to the docs  it is a *Dictionary from which to save matfile variables.*

Comment: Your understanding is right, the first `alist` is the name in the matfile and the second `alist` the content you want to store in this variable name. For more than one variable create a dictionary with more than one element.

Comment: Thanks guys - I had read the dictionary docs but using dictionaries has been a bit foreign coming to me from C++. Clarification on assigning the variable name vs. the data that I am assigning to it (and some figuring out of the {key:value} notation) got me through this - thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs, `savemat` is defined as

```
io.savemat(file_name, mdict, appendmat=True, format='5', long_field_names=False, do_compression=False, oned_as='row')
```

So the 2nd argument is required, and may be provided with or without the `mdict=...` part.

The reason why it expects this to be a dictionary is that it needs to know the name(s) under which the variable (data) is saved.  If it accepted a variable it would have to make up a name.  In Python syntax, these 2 expresions pass the same thing to `foo`.  The name "alist" is not passed in any way to `foo`.

```
alist = np.arange(10)
foo('test.mat', alist)

foo('test.mat', np.arange(10))
```

`loadmat` also returns a dictionary, for example:

```
{'__version__': '1.0',
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Mon May 25 09:19:36 2015',
 '__globals__': [],
 'alist': array([[1, 2, 3]])}
```

And when I `load text.mat` in `octave`, a `alist` variable appears in the workspace.

The functional form of `load` produces a `structure`

```
octave:5> r=load('test.mat')
r =
  scalar structure containing the fields:
    alist =
      1  2  3
```

The corresponding `octave` functional form of `save` is

```
save ("-option1", ..., "file", "v1", ...)
```

where `"v1"` is the name of the variable you want to save.

`octave/MATLAB` pulls the values for these variables from the global namespace.  That kind of action is (more strongly) discouraged in Python.

```
save('-7','test1.mat',"alist")
```

in `octave` loads as

```
In [1256]: io.loadmat('test1.mat')
Out[1256]: 
{'__version__': '1.0',
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, written by Octave 3.8.1, 2015-05-25 17:02:15 UTC',
 '__globals__': [],
 'alist': array([[1, 2, 3]])}
```

Except for header content it is the same.